# AttributeError: 'KerasTPUModel' object has no attribute '_run_eagerly'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am using **tf.kaeras in google colab with python3.0 notebook** and getting the error with the following code:

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[Inp], outputs=[output])

tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(
            tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
    )
)

tpu_model.fit(
  train_input_fn,
  steps_per_epoch = 60,
  epochs=epochs)
```

**And the error message is**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d6a0cf977e09> in <module>()
      2   train_input_fn,
      3   steps_per_epoch = 60,
----> 4   epochs=epochs)
      5 
      6 score = tpu_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in run_eagerly(self)
    399       Boolean, whether the model should run eagerly.
    400     """
--> 401     if self._run_eagerly is True and not context.executing_eagerly():
    402       raise ValueError('You can only set `run_eagerly=True` if eager execution '
    403                        'is enabled.')

AttributeError: 'KerasTPUModel' object has no attribute '_run_eagerly'
```

**INFO:**

I get this error in google colab. Here is the Python and tensorflow version.

```
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
print("Python Version:", sys.version_info)
print("TensorFlow Version:", tf.__version__)
```

> Python Version: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>   TensorFlow Version: 1.14.0-rc1

Comment: Can you provide your python version 'python -V' along with your tensorflow version 'python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'?

Comment: I added the information in question for the benefit of wider visibility. Thank you.